# Is it possible to observer and manipulate what is shown on the screen in realtime?

Tags: android, android-studio, blur

Is there any way to see what is being displayed on the screen and manipulate it. Basically I want to run an NSFW filter which blurs NSFW content on phone.

I want to do this regardless of what app is running on the phone etc.

I have tried searching some examples but nothing particular came up.

Answer (score 0):

Please someone figure out how to do this on modern phones, I've been trying for months. However, if you have an older phone that doesn't have the latest version of Android 'Cover Photo Lock' works well.